# webpack mix error in ubuntu 18

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, vue.js

when i run ( npm run watch ) this error occur !!

> @ development /home/nader/Desktop/asd/blog
>
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

```
module.js:549throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/nader/Desktop/asd/blog/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)

at Module.require (module.js:596:17)

at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

at requireConfig (/home/nader/Desktop/asd/blog/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:97:18)

at /home/nader/Desktop/asd/blog/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:104:17

at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

at module.exports (/home/nader/Desktop/asd/blog/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:102:15)

at yargs.parse (/home/nader/Desktop/asd/blog/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:171:41)

at Object.Yargs.self.parse (/home/nader/Desktop/asd/blog/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:533:18)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

.... . . ..

help please ????

Comment: try deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a file `webpack.config.js` at the path `/home/nader/Desktop/asd/blog/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/`? npm is saying it can't find the package there.  Try npm installing the laravel-mix package again